# How to find the analytical representation of eigenvalues of the matrix $G$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following matrix arising when I tried to discretize the Green function， now to show the convergence of my algorithm I need to find the eigenvalues of the matrix $G$ and show it has absolute value less than 1 for certain choices of $N$.

Note that the explicit formula for entry $(i,j)$ is $-i(N+1-j)$ when $i\le j$ and it is symmetric, so we can get the formulas for $i>j$ by interchanging $i$ and $j$ in the $i\le j$ case.

Any one has any ideas about how to find the analytical representation of eigenvalues of the matrix $G$, i,e, the eigenvalues represented by $N$? Thank you so much for any help!

$\begin{pmatrix}
 - N & - N + 1 & -N+2 & -N+3 &\ldots & 1(-2) & 1(-1) \\
 - N + 1 & 2( - N + 1) & 2(-N+2) & 2(-N+3) &\ddots & 2(-2) & 2(-1) \\
 - N + 2 & 2( - N + 2) & 3(-N+2) & 3(-N+3) &\ddots & 3(-2) & 3(-1) \\
 - N + 3 & 2( - N + 3) & 3(-N+3) & 4(-N+3) &\ddots & 4(-2) & 4(-1) \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
 - 2 & 2(-2) & 3(-2) & 4(-2) &\ddots & ( - 1 + N)( - 2) & ( - 1 + N)( - 1) \\
 - 1 & 2(-1) & 3(-1) & 4(-1) &\ldots & ( - 1 + N)( - 1) & N( - 1) \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: This matrix looks either circulant or nearly so, there are general explicit formulae for circulant matrices and there are theories for asymptotic approximation of "near circulant matrices" by actual circulant matrices.

Comment: Do you have an explicit formula for the entry $(i,j)$?

Comment: @Arash Yes, I do. See my update the explicit formula for entry $(i,j)$ is $-i(N+1-j)$

Comment: @Arash Sorry the formula is actually $-i(N+1-j)$ when $i\le j$ and it is symmetric.

Comment: I don't understand your definition of the matrix $G$. How is $G^{(s)}$ related to $G$? How is the numerator $h$ defined? And you said $G$ is symmetric, but it isn't: $g_{ij}=-i(N+1-j)\ne-j(N+1-i)=g_{ji}$.

Comment: @user1551 Sorry that I am not clear about the formula. It is symmetric and for entry $(i,j)$ is $-i(N+1-j)$ when $i\le j$, while the formulas for $i>j$, we have the formulas by interchanging $i$ and $j$. Sorry again.

Comment: @user1551 About how I get the matrix $G$, it will be a long description. Basically I am using the Green's function integration formula to express the analytical solution of the pde. Then I discretize the Green's function to get a numerical expression for the integral, which resulted in the above matrix $G$. Hope I am clear about this. Thank you!

Comment: @user1551 And the $h$ here is the step size, but I think it doesn't effect the eigenvalues, since we can take it out of the matrix as a constant.

Comment: @Ian Thank you so much for your suggestion! It is really helpful. Could you give me some references for this problem? I tried a lot and can only find the case the diagonals are constant which is not the case here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I actually misunderstood your notation prior to the edit, my suggestion is not applicable.

Comment: Sherry: Why do you not accept @NoName's answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Eigenvalues of matrix $G$ are
$$\lambda_k(G)=-\tfrac{1}{4}(N+1)\sin^{-2}\left(\frac{k\pi}{2(N+1)}\right)\,,\quad k=1,\ldots,N\,.$$

To prove the statement, we start by writing elements of matrix $G$ as $g_{ij}=ij-(N+1)\min(i,j)$.
Next, we define matrix $L$ as a lower triangular matrix with all elements in the lower triangle equal to one, i.e. $l_{ij}=1$ for $i\geq j$ and $l_{ij}=0$ for $i<j$, and we define vector $\mathbf{1}$ as a vector of ones.
This enables us to write
$$G=(L\mathbf{1})(L\mathbf{1})^T-(N+1)LL^T = L(\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T-(N+1)I)L^T\,.$$

Since $L^{-1}$ is bidiagonal matrix with $1$ on the diagonal and $-1$ on the subdiagonal, we hoped inverting $G$ would result in a matrix with more zero elements.
Using [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) to invert $\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T-(N+1)I$, we obtain
$$G^{-1}=\frac{-1}{N+1}L^{-T}(I+\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T)L^{-1} = \frac{-1}{N+1}\begin{bmatrix}\hphantom{-}2 & -1 & & 0\\-1 & \ddots & \ddots\\ & \ddots & \ddots & -1\\0 & & -1 & \hphantom{-}2\end{bmatrix}\,.$$

This matrix is a tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix, and there is analytical expression for eigenvalues of such matrices, see [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Eigenvalues) for example. In our case 
$$\lambda_k(G^{-1}) = \frac{-2}{N+1}+\frac{2}{N+1}\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{N+1}\right) = \frac{-4}{N+1}\sin^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{2(N+1)}\right)\,,\quad k=1,\ldots,N\,.$$
Now, our statement follows from eiganvalues of $G$ being reciprocals of eigenvalues of $G^{-1}$.